# Change proxy's response header through Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, response-headers

I have an instance of Nginx Plus deployed as a reverse proxy. The proxy app returns a "set-cookie" header in the response which I'd like to modify (the domain associated with the to-be cookie):

Change

set-cookie:key=value;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=**my.domain.net**

to

set-cookie:key=value;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=**new.domain.com**

Needless to say I can't modify the application to use something like an outbound rewrite rule.

Comment: Have you tried the [`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) directive?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was what I needed. This should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nginx http proxy module has two directives which manipulate the “Set-Cookie” header in the response from the upstream server.

[`proxy_cookie_path`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path) can change the path attribute of the “Set-Cookie” header.

[`proxy_cookie_domain`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain) can change the domain attribute of the “Set-Cookie” header.